# Why is jQuery UI dialog opening 2 modals in IE8?

Tags: jquery-ui, internet-explorer-8, jquery-ui-dialog

I have a jQuery.post() run whenever a particular button is clicked:

```
function createNewImage () {
    jQuery.post("create/new/image.php", {some:params}, function (data) {
        loadImageSelector(data);
    }, "json");
}
```

when `create/new/image.php` has run successfully and the server is ready to accept and attach an image to a newly created database row, we open up this jQuery UI dialog modal:

```
function loadImageSelector(data) {
    jQuery('<iframe src="script.php?id=' + data.param + '" /></iframe>').dialog({
        modal: true,
        width: 500,
        height: 400,
        resizable: false,
        title: "Upload an Image"
    });
}
```

The problem is that on IE8 I see 2 dialogs popup. 1 contains the full contents of `script.php` and looks correct, but on top of this is another dialog that has only a header ("Upload an Image") and a close button – no content (the iframe). This behavior is not occurring in IE9/Chrome/Firefox.

Comment: No error in the console ? What happens when debugging ? Difficult to help you without experiencing the problem...

Comment: Yea, this will be a tough one to track down. No errors in console, 1 dialog in all browsers but IE8. I mostly was hoping someone had encountered this before, but the only similar questions I'm seeing are related to an infinite loop of loading dialogs. Perhaps this is related somehow...

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of interesting. The code above is closing 2 iframes and IE8 is somehow reacting and creating 2 modals.

The first tag closes itself via `/>` but then includes another `</iframe>` tag afterwards. This was accidental, but I find it interesting that it responds like this.

Anyways, ensuring that the markup exists as it should (`<iframe ...></iframe>`) fixed the problem.